# iOS Swift: how to check if Object exists in an Array so I don't add it to it, or re-create a GMSMarker with it?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-maps

I've been working with gmaps for iOS sdk and have this problem: each time the map pans or zooms *and finishes*(Im using the Delegate *idleAtCameraPosition*) in my serverside I compare the coordinates of the center of the map, in order to mark pins of places around it.  I save the places in an array of "Places" objects, when they are close enough(1km) from the center coordinates.

My problem is that I haven't been able to avoid adding repeated objects to the array, so every time I do pan the map but don't change the camera position that much, the existing markers in the screen are re-added to the Places array.  I tried using this code, but it doesn't work and the array can grow infinitely until crashing the app:

```
   if(!arrayProp.contains(place)){
      arrayProp.append(place)
   }
```

but it doesn't work.

I also have another array of GMSMarkers that feeds itself from the Places array; tried this code to avoid re-creating markers in the map with Places objects that already existed:

```
for place in arrayProp {
                let pinPlace = PlaceMarker(propied: place)//custom GMSMarker class
                if(self.markerArray.contains(pinPlace) == false ) {
                    self.markerArray.append(pinPlace)
                    pinPlace.map = self.mapaGoogle
                } else {
                    pinPlace.map = nil
                }
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `Place` is using a default definition of Equatable which is not what you expect. You'll need something like this for contains() to work as expected:

```
struct Place: Equatable {
    let there: Bool
}

func ==(lhs: Place, rhs: Place) -> Bool {
    return lhs.there == rhs.there
}
```

Check Place's definition, or create one if it's using a default that checks only the necessary fields.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a Set? Swift supports a Set collection type that handles uniqueness for you. The type you store in the set just needs to implement Hashable, which you can implement on your GMSMarker class. (Or, if it's not your class, you can add an extension to implement the Hashable protocol)

[See Apple's documentation on Sets.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: I have a question: the documentation says that the hashValue may not be the same in every run of the program.  If that's true, then I'm thinking this:

If I store an object in the Set, and then get the same object through json and compare it to the one stored in the Set, because the hashValue may not remain the same both objects could have a different hashValue and hence the new object will be added to the Set, making the data to be repeated again.

Would it be?

Comment: I know there are certain properties that should be validated in order to have the Hashable protocol in the object, such as reflexivity and such.  But I would like to know if this scenario I just mentioned can be expected

Comment: Yes, that would be an issue, but you should implement Hashable yourself so you can prevent this from happening. Does your json data include unique id's for each object? Just use those ids for `hashValue`. Otherwise, you'll need to build up a hashValue yourself based on the values of each property in your `PlaceMarker` class. See this example: http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/

Comment: yes, my objects have a unique id each.  Can I use them for the hashValue?

Comment: Im still trying to grasp the implementation concept of it.  I'll work on this and then make notice if this answered my question; thank you

Comment: GMSMarker has already an implementation of Hashable and Equatable, you can't override the Equatable one

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading all of the new objects anyways, then you can just empty out the existing array before adding the new values. `self.markerArray.removeAll()` then add your new objects.

Comment: because we are talking about markers on a map, I want to keep those already displaying and just add more as the user goes zooming and panning the screen.  

I don't know, but I thought deleting and re-drawing all the markers on the screen will hinder performance and make the map freeze when deleting and redrawing every time, so I decided not to do this